# Do the words 'poster' and 'mixer' have one or two morphemes?

Tags: morphology, derivational-morphology, morphemes

The words 'Driver', 'writer' and 'player' are composed of base and -er morpheme, which have the meaning of the one who writes or drives..., whereas 'mixer' doesn't mean the one who mixes, does it mean it is composed of just one morpheme?

The same for 'poster'.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, probably. They each have several meanings, of course.

Comment: why do you say that the word mixer does not mean the one/thing that mixes?

Comment: I went to a company mixer last night, the sound system had an audio mixer. They demoed some new sound effects- one of which was made by recording a kitchen mixer and slowing it way down.

Comment: The original poster seems certain too that a poster is not one who posts

Comment: A morpheme is the smallest unit of meaning found within a word, which may be the word itself — but you know that, of course. What you may not know is that you can find this answer — and many others like it! — by looking up a word's etymology.Try etymonline.com for a free and fairly accurate source.

Comment: Also, perhaps you could revise this question so that it is not based on a faulty premise (i.e., that mixer does not mean "one who mixes").

Comment: [Mixer](http://ak1.ostkcdn.com/images/products/5285941/5285941/KitchenAid-KSM155GBCA-Candy-Apple-Red-5-quart-Artisan-Design-Tilt-Head-Stand-Mixer-With-Bonus-Rebate-Item-P13099243.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

A brief visit to the *OED* finds that the "-er" suffix attached to a verb may come from the Latin suffix *-arius* (masculine) or *-arium* (neuter).  If the former, the word refers to a person associated with the action of the verb, which gives rise to the notion of agency; if the latter, it's a thing so associated.

So we can attach -er to a verb to refer to a person who does what the verb means: "He is a mixer of metaphors" or to a thing associated with the action of the verb:  "No ginger ale?  What other mixers do you have?"  In the same way a "poster" may be one who posts messages or the placard placed by such a poster.

In either case, two morphemes.

Comment: So is a ginger a person who ginges? :)

Comment: I have never heard of the verb **to ginge**, maybe it's when you paint your hair ginger?

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole And you assumed that every word ending in -er must be derived from verb + -er, why?

Comment: No, but it's the most logical thing I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

I could look up "poster art" on the web, find some posters for sale, and order one for myself.  But then the thing that I bought, the "poster", would never have been on a post and would not have been intended ever to go on a post, or to be posted anywhere.  If it has no connection with any post, how can we say that "post" is a meaningful part of its form?

Is this what concerns you?  I agree that it's a problem.

On the other hand, even in the situation I described above, there is *some* connection with "post".  The poster I sent off for is *reminiscent* of things which are meant to be posted, or at least were meant to be, once upon a time.  Even if I never post the thing, it's about the size of the things that have been posted, in the past, and it has some meaningful inscription on it, as other posters have had.

So that's my answer.  You haven't yet found an instance of an -er form that has no connection whatever to the morpheme that the -er form is attached to.  Look further.  Perhaps you will.

Comment: So the examples given were bad because they do derive from words that have an "er" morphene (and well explained there), but if better words had been chosen (ginger, alter, manger, lager, ether, other) then I think that question should be answered (even if with a trivial "yes") to make this an answer.

Answer (score -2):

In Latin the suffix -tor was used for acting person. In most cases such words were derived from verbs. Latin auctor gives English author. We may assume that this suffix developed from a present participle stem + or for male person. So the verb augere has the participle stem augent. Augent+ or can be shortent to auctor.

Already in Latin such word formations could be used metaphorically for tools or machines that were used to perform an action. Motor is not a person moving something but an engine moving a car.

So this Latin suffix -tor is etymologically one and the same suffix. Whether specialists of morphology  see the suffix for person and non-person as one suffix or two is a thing they have to decide.

@Janus -My experience is that most Latin nouns ending in -tor are acting persons as orator, defensor, quaestor senator and this is also the view of Heinichen, a lexicographer who has lists of Latin suffixes in his dictionaries. He says --tor acting person and -trix (-tor+ix) acting person, female. If no formations of the type participle stem + or are found you can assume that the suffix -tor  fell from the sky. I assume they must have a logical development and the derivation from a participle is logical. Of course, such formations were shortened because a formation as *orantor becomes too long and  omission of n is a frequent change in Latin.

Comment: The fact that the _-ter/-tor_ suffix is never found with the actual present participle stem in any of the many languages that have it is pretty sure-fire evidence that it is not attached to the present participle stem with some mysterious syncope (that does not happen anywhere else in any language, either). _-or_ is also not a suffix for “male person”.

Comment: I think @Janus was asking: why the *present participle* rather than the *infinitive* or another form of the verb?